# Displaying two list items per line maximum, responsive layout CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a page that contains list items. These are displayed differently depending on the width of the window. Before the first breakpoint they appear in a mobile style layout:

[IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/zx8djt.png[/IMG]

After the second breakpoint, the pictures expand and become circular remained centred (I would post an image of this but am only allowed 1 link)

A maximum of two list items should be displayed per line at all times when the width goes past a certain threshold, the third breakpoint.

If I apply 
    float: left;

to the list items, they will all appear on one line but I can't seem to accomplish the desired effect.

Any help with the solution would be greatly helpful as I've been going back and forth on this for 2 hours now to no avail.

Here is the code (Keep in mind this is for a college assignment and the HTML cannot be altered):

HTML

```
    <div id="userContainer">
<h2> Users</h2>


<ul id = "users">

    <li>
        <img  src = "pic1.jpg">
        <div class  = "data">J Doe</div>

    </li>


    <li>    
        <img  src = "pic2.jpg"> 
        <div class  = "data"> J Smith</div>

    </li>


    <li>
        <img src = "pic3.jpg">
        <div class  = "data"> L O'Brien</div>
    </li>



    <li>
        <img  src = "pic4.jpg">
        <div class  = "data"> S Fanning</div>
    </li>


    <li>
        <img  src = "pic5.jpg">
        <div class  = "data"> M Brown</div>
    </li>

</ul>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
li{
list-style-type: none;
background-color: black;
width: 150px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border-radius: 50%;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Edit: [IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/11biw6w.png[/IMG] - This is the desired effect for when the browser window goes past about 700px

Comment: Post your code please. That way we can give help tailored to your example.

Comment: Set 50% width on the floated lis

Answer (score 0):

You should simply control the width of the div with media queries.

Post your code here to help you more. IN which div are these images?

```
@media screen and (min-width:700px){ /* the threshold  */
div{width: 500px;}
}
@media screen and (max-width:699px){ /* the threshold  */
div{width: 250px;}
}
```